# Character Jumping Issue - Floats away before jump is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, character

I am trying to make my character jump, but the character moves up before the jump button is pressed. It also does not come back, just floats away.

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {
     public float speed;
     void Update () {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
             rigidbody.AddForce (Vector3.up * 10);
             Debug.Log("Space has been pressed");
         }
     }


     void FixedUpdate () {
         {
             float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
             float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

             Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
             rigidbody.AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
             rigidbody.AddForce (Vector3.up * 10);
         }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fixed update, you've told it to move your character up with AddForce.  I think you meant to say * -10 rather than * 10 (I'm assuming this is you applying gravity manually) or maybe you didn't mean to have that line there at all?